# passing value from one page to another but it shows error message when it does query with this value in PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP I passed a value through URL from one page to the other page, on the other page I use $_REQUEST variable to get this value and I get, but when I write sqlquery it does not get, if I check its value with var_dump() method.. it shows boolean(false).solve it please

page1:

```
<strike>
 <select onchange="location=this.value">
 <option value="adminViewContact" active>View Contact Group</option>
  <?php 
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
   {
    echo ' <option value="userViewContactGroup.php?    id='.$row['user_id'].' &&  var='.$row['rel_name'].'   ">'.$row['rel_name'].'</option> ';                                         
  }
?> 
 </select>
</strike>
```

page2:

```
<strike>
<?php 
 if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && isset($_REQUEST['var']))
 {
  $id= $_REQUEST['id'] ;
  $relation1= $_REQUEST['var'] ;
 }
 $Query1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contact WHERE st_contact_id=$id AND    rel_status==$relation1 ";
?>
</strike>
```

this is my while loop use to retrive database value but it does not work.:

```
<?php 
$Query1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contact WHERE st_contact_id=$id AND rel_status='$relation1' ";
$result1 = mysql_query($Query1);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{   
    $i++;
?>
<tr class="info">
    <td><?php  echo $i ; ?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $row['firststname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $row['address']; ?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php  echo $row['contact_date']; ?</td>
    <td><?php  echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php                   
}                                               
?>
```

Comment: you could put the source code here?

Comment: Share your code what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hello Brother, I submitted my code just now please check it....thanks @ExtremsX

Comment: Where is your `var_dump`?

Comment: thanks brother....I use var_dump() to check whats value its return....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**
`rel_status==$relation1` is wrong in sql.

you must use `rel_status='$relation1'`.

and I think your problem will solve.

**2.**
you should replace

`echo ' <option value="userViewContactGroup.php?    id='.$row['user_id'].' &&  var='.$row['rel_name'].'   ">'.$row['rel_name'].'</option> ';`

with:

`echo "<option value='userViewContactGroup.php?id=".$row['user_id'].'&  var='.$row['rel_name']."'>".$row['rel_name']."</option>";`

Comment: @ashik what is the type of `rel_status` in the database??

Comment: rel_status varchar(100)

Comment: @ashik please apply step 2 and tell me what is the result.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: @ashik excuse me. I was edited the code. please try the new one.

Comment: @ashik I'm sorry. if you put more information about your pages, I can help you solve the problem. but with the current information I can't help you more than this ;)

Comment: @ashik you're welcome. you can select my answer and vote up if it was helpful for you ;)